# OleDbDataReader reading blank rows from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Not sure what is going on as I've used the `OleDbDataReader` before to pull data off an Excel spreadsheet, but suddenly my C# batch job is not stopping at blank rows via the `while(_reader.Reader())` loop.

Here is the C# code I'm using. I'm simply trying to pull all the record off an Excel spreadsheet and loop through the data right now. For some reason, though, the `_reader.Read()` function comes back `true` no matter what.

```
    private static OleDbDataReader _reader;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= \\prdhilfs03\l&i-sales&mkt\WORKAREA\Agencyservices\Shared\AIC\Analysts_and_Reporting\Realignments\2014\MassUpdateTesting\Validate\ZipCodeTest.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [Query1$]";

        Validation validation;
        ZipCodeTerritory record;

        bool flag = true;
        try
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                //Set connection objects to pull from spreadsheet
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                _reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                //Instantiate validation object with zip and channel values
                _allRecords = GetRecords();
                validation = new Validation();
                validation.SetLists(_allRecords);

                while (_reader.Read())
                {
                    record = new ZipCodeTerritory();
                    record.ChannelCode = _reader[0].ToString();
                    record.DrmTerrDesc = _reader[1].ToString();
                    record.IndDistrnId = _reader[2].ToString();
                    record.StateCode = _reader[3].ToString().Trim();
                    record.ZipCode = _reader[4].ToString().Trim();
                    record.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_reader[5].ToString());
                    record.EffectiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_reader[6].ToString());
                    record.LastUpdateId = _reader[7].ToString();
                    record.ErrorCodes = _reader[8].ToString();
                    record.Status = _reader[9].ToString();
                    record.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;


                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.LastUpdateId))
                    {
                        //Add to error list
                        _issues++;
                        _errorList.Add(record, "Missing last update Id");
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (_reader[10] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        record.Id = Convert.ToInt32(_reader[10]);
                    }

                    _errorMsg = validation.ValidateZipCode(record);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_errorMsg))
                    {
                        _errorList.Add(record, _errorMsg);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (flag)
                    {
                        //Separate updates to appropriate list
                        SendToUpdates(record);
                    }

                    //Console.WriteLine(record.Id.ToString());
                }
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025983/how-to-upload-only-non-empty-rows-of-excel-spreadsheet-using-oledb-in-c) on stack overflow and tried to follow the selected answer by changing the `queryString` to the following. However, this simply throws an `OleDbException` when the `OleDbCommand` runs its `.ExecuteReader()` method. (the `Message` property of the exception reads "No value given for one or more required parameters")

`SELECT * FROM [Query1$] WHERE NOT ([ChannelCode] = '' and [DrmTerrDec] = '' and [StateCode] = '' and [ZipCode] = '' and [EndDate] = '' and [EffectiveDate] = '')`

**EDIT**

Just added all the code inside the `while` loop.

Comment: You may want to paste the code in the while block that _reader.Read() is using.

Comment: Just added to the post. thx

Answer (score 2):

This helped me

```
dataTable = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => !row.ItemArray.All(field => field is System.DBNull || string.Compare((field as string).Trim(), string.Empty) == 0)).CopyToDataTable();e
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233678